# Find the limit of $a_n$ = sin($n$)sin($1/n$) from real analysis point of view

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Find the limit of the following sequence:

$a_n$ = sin($n$)·sin($1/n$)

I know that by limit theorems, lim(sin($n$)·sin($1/n$)) = lim(sin($n$)) ·lim(sin($1/n$)

Obviously, lim sin(n) = undefined & lim sin(1/n) = 0

How do I  find this limit from real analysis standpoint?

Comment: $\lim \sin(n)$ may be undefined, but $\sin(n)$ is nicely bounded.

Comment: Try to prove: sequence converging to zero time a bounded sequence converges to zero.

Comment: That is helpful because I do know how to prove that. since we would know that there exists $M$ > 0 such that |$b_n$|< M for all n... I have proven this on another homework problem. Now I just need to figure out how to find lim sin(1/n)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I am not missing aprt of the question.

When $n$ is large $\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is close to $\frac{1}{n}$, so $\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sin (n)$ behaves as $\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ and $-1 < \sin (n) <1$. So, $a_n$ is bounded by the two curves given by $-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. So, if $n$ goes to infinity, $a_n$ goes to zero by positive or negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $-1 \le \sin(n) \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

/a(n)/ < /sin(1/n)/ --> 0. Use squeeze theorem to get lim = 0

Comment: I'm not sure what to put as the right hand side of the inequality so I can find a limit

Comment: would this work?

$a_n$ < sin(1/n) < sin(1/n) / (1/n) < 1/n    ??

Comment: sin(1/n) < 1/n works fine.